# No Managed Code option not available in IIS 10

Tags: .net-core, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I am trying to run a dotnet core application in IIS 10 which requires the Managed Pipeline Mode be set to "No Managed Code" but that option appears to be missing. Am I missing a setting or a framework to enable that option?